# How to store an object in django sessions framework

Tags: django, redirect, httpresponse, django-sessions

I have an django and i am trying to store an object in django session varaible, and trying to access that in the redirected view, but its showing `keyerror`  as below

```
def payment(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CardForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            response = response_from_payment_gateway(data)
            request.session['response'] = response
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('paygate:payment_success'))
    else:
        form = CardForm(initial={'number':'4242424242424242'})
    return render_to_response('payment_form.html',{'form': form})


def PaymentSuccess(request):
    print request.session['response'],"=================>"
    response = None
    return render_to_response("payment_success.html", {'response':response}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Result**

```
Internal Server Error: /payment/success/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Envs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/virtualenvironment/apps/app/payment/views.py", line 120, in PaymentSuccess
    print request.session['response'],"=================>"
  File "/home/Envs/app/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 46, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
KeyError: 'response'
```

So i am getting back a response object from the payment gateway that contains the transaction details, and i am trying to save that in `session framework variable` called `response` as above.

And i am trying to access the variable called `response` in the redirected view `PaymentSuccess` as `request.session['response']`, and getting the above mentioned error.

so how can we send/save the objects in the `sessions` in django ?

In above the response object will be of the following form

```
{'status': 'SUCCESS', 'response': <Charge charge id=ch_2OXdxxxxNVw at 0xb508e76cL> JSON: {
  "amount": 100, 
  "amount_refunded": 0, 
  "balance_transaction": "txxxn_xxxxxxxxO", 
  "captured": true, 
 "currency": "usd", 
  "customer": null, 
  "description": null, 
}}
```

Comment: are you directly visiting /payment/success.In that case, you will receive that error.

Comment: sorry din't get u, what does that mean by `directly visiting` ?, if the form is valid i will get response from gateway and trying to store that response in session and redirecting to another page, and trying to use that session in redirected page, this is i am trying to do :)

Comment: Could you do something like this ,and tell me the output. Construct an object of Response and serialize it from django.core.serializers to json format and store it in session. then get it from session deserialize it and  get an object and access it.Pure guess though.

Comment: actually as u can observer `response['response']` is an json object right even though its displaying keyerror

Comment: `response': <Charge charge id=ch_2OXdxxxxNVw at 0xb508e76cL> JSON:`

Comment: Do you have sessions in installed apps? Did you run syncdb after installing them (just to check)

Comment: @ J. C. Leitão : yes i have actually `'django.contrib.sessions',`

Answer (score -1):

the interpreter never reaches this part

```
request.session['response'] = response
```

this means that either our form isn't valid or the method of the request isn't POST

try to replace

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

with

```
if request.POST:
```

and if it doesn't work set the request.session['response'] to any other value  just to make sure that the sessions framework isn't broken.
You need to debug further, I'm 100% sure that this isn't a session problem.

Comment: actually when i use `request.session['response'] = 1`, its working fine and can be able to print that in `paymentsuccess` view, but when i tried to do the same with `response object`, i mean when we try to save a response object instead of integer, its not working

Comment: Even after replacing with `request.POST`, i am getting same  `KeyError: 'response'`

Comment: I usually use sessions to store user instances as a login service. I'm still sure that you need to debug further.

Comment: k anyway can u show code how u will `use sessions to store user instances` ?, so that may be i will get some idea what i am doing wrong !!!!